# Storing and receiving information

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently trying to create a simple text-based city simulator game. I'm still in the early stages learning python so I'll try my best at explaining my issue.

My little game has a construction function:

```
def construct(): # Construction order
    print ("What do you want to construct?")
    print ("Type 'help' for a list of buildings.")
    command = input()
    if command == 'help':
        print_buildings() # Prints a list of the different buildings
    elif command in building_types: # If the command is a key in the list 'building_types'
        amount = int(input("How many? "))
        build(building_types[command], amount) # Call the function 'build'
```

The build function is the part that got me scratching my head. When you first look at it it's fairly obvious what to.
The build function should be like:

```
def build(command, amount):
    building_amount[command] += amount
```

But the building doesn't just get constructed in an instance. Depending on the building type it takes longer for the building to get constructed. For that I have the 'next_day' function:

```
def next_day():
    global money
    global day
    total = income - expense # The total of the days' income and expense
    money += total # The total is added to the money
    day += 1 # Next day
    main_menu() # Goes back to the menu
```

I want the building to be constructed after 'x' amount of days. How would I go about doing this? Thanks in advance for anyone willing to help.

(Excuse my bad spelling or phrasing. English isn't my first language.)

- Edit 1: fixed indentation
- Edit 2: temporarily fixed argument issue

Comment: Fixed. Sorry about that.

Comment: I'm still kind of unclear on what you are trying to ask/accomplish so I can't help, sorry, but this should at least be getting `TypeError: build() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)` since in your `elif` you are calling it with only one argument (`build(building_types[command])`).

Comment: No problem. I have temporarily fixed the arguments issue.

Comment: Why not make each building an object? Create a building class, with local variables such as `time_to_build`. Store these objects in a list/dictionary, and each time `next_day()` is called, decrement `time_to_build` for each object that is not built, and use a function within this building class to check if `time_to_build` is `0`, then "build" it. Something along those lines may suffice.

Comment: Thanks alot! I dont know much about classes yet but i will make an attempt at creating some.